# how to pass parameter value to saveAsTable() option in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I need to parameterize the table value in *saveAsTable()* option in Spark.
can anyone please suggest
I tried ***saveAsTable("$tablename")*** but it didn't work out and throwing error.

Comment: extraneous input '.' expecting .. similar kind of error. I need to parameterize the database name in the saveAsTable option something like below  saveAsTable($dB name.tablename)

Comment: It would be just helpful if you can please let me know how to use a parameter within saveAsTable() option. I want to parameterize Database name within SAVEASTABLE option

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, Use `string interpolation` i.e append `s` to before "$tablename" string.

```
saveAsTable(s"$tablename")
```